# Add API documentation to website using Swagger document

Tags: json, html, api, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a basic webpage built, and a Swagger document JSON file of my API. I am unsure of how to actually add the data from the document to the website so that it can be browsed.

I want to build hosted documentation for the API.

This is the example given by Swagger: http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/#!/pet/addPet

Do I just download Swagger UI and use it in conjunction with the JSON file.

But I am unsure on to achieve this. Any advice on how to go about creating something like this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger-ui is basically a set of static files you can host on your server to display your API.

Unless you may any major changes, you just need to copy the contents of the /dist folder to your server and host it as part of your application (or static website, doesn't matter).

The [SwaggerUi](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#swaggerui) object can be customized to your needs, including the URL of the spec you're hosting.

Keep in mind that if you don't host the ui and spec on the same server, (that is, same host and same port), you need to enable [CORS](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#cors-support).

Comment: 3 years have gone by, and I find your answer very helpful. Thank you, sir.